# provider.broadcastTransaction is not a function

Tags: contract-development, evm

I'm trying to call a contract function on the avalanche network. However I'm running into this error. Interestingly, the transaction goes through on hardhat network however fails on a evm testnest (fuji).

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue can be caused from differences between the hardhat network and the Avalanche Fuji testnet.

It's possible that the contract function relies on some unique characteristic of the hardhat network, or there could be a difference in gas costs or transaction speed.

To resolve this problem, you should compare the behavior and settings of the two networks, as well as double-check the contract function code for any environment-specific conditions.

Thanks.